# How do I differentiate this integral within an integral with respect to t? $b(t) =\int_0^t (k(e^{-(\mu+\gamma)x})\int_0^t e^{-ky} dy)dx$

Tags: derivatives, definite-integrals

I have the following equation and I need to differentiate it with respect to t (to get $b'(t)$).

> $$b(t) =\int_0^t (k(e^{-(\mu+\gamma)x})\int_0^t e^{-ky} dy)dx.$$

I am confused as to how to deal with the integral within an integral. Since we are differentiating with respect to t, is there a trick that can be used since t is the upper limit of the integral?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, write the integral as
$$ b(t) =\int_0^t (k(e^{-(\mu+\gamma)x})\int_0^t e^{-ky} dy)dx
 =\int_0^t k\,e^{-(\mu+\gamma)x}dx\int_0^t e^{-ky} dy=f(t)g(t).$$

Now, just use the product rule.

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks very much.

Comment: @Chris: You are very welcome.